# Javascript Datatable Time Sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I'm trying to do something with JavaScript DataTable but I'm stuck somewhere .

There are 2 DataTable on the same page .
I am sending data from the first DataTable second DataTable . I can write in the footer section that collects in the second DataTable int .

I collect information on hours in a second column in the DataTable I want to write a footer . I could not do it.

How do you think I should proceed . Existing employees script below.

Thank you to everyone.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#FlowList').DataTable({
            rowReorder: true,
                 "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api(), data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function ( i ) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };

                // Tüm sayfaların toplamı
                      total = api
                    .column( 3 )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Gösterilen sayfanın toplamı
                     pageTotal = api
                    .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                    // Footer Güncelleme
                    $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                        /* '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' Toplam)'  */
                        'Toplam ' + total
                    );
                }
            });

    var counter = 1;
    var table = $('#NewsListTable').DataTable();

    $('#NewsListTable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function(){
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        //alert(data[3]);

        t.row.add( [
            counter +'', //Sıra numarasını her seferinde 1 arttırıyoruz.
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
            data[6],
            data[7],
            data[8]
        ]
        ).draw( false );

        counter++;

    });
});

</script>
```